# select points within circles within square perimeter

Tags: r

I have a vector of coordinates where each row designates the centre of a circle:

```
x <- runif(5,0,2)
y <- runif(5,0,2)
```

As you can see the circles centres are all found within the square (0,2).

Each circle has a radius 0.2. I want to randomly shift the centre of the circles within the bounds of the original circle. I figured I could do this:

```
radii  <- (sample(20,5,replace=TRUE))/100
angles <- sample(360,5,replace=TRUE)
newx <- x + radii*(cos(angles))
newy <- y + radii*(sin(angles))
```

However, I realise that doing this I could technically get circle centres that fall outside of the square (0,2).  I could try and write a loop that rejects `newx` and `newy` values that are negative. But have to do this for 10s of thousands of rows and worried about the speed of this. Is it possible to run this conditional coordinate shift without resorting to a loop?

My rule set is as follows:

1. pick a new circle centre for each centre.
2. The new centres must fall within the area of each circle (radius 0.2 distance from the original centre)
3. The new centres must lie within the original square.
4. If a centre meets the border of the circle it should be reflected as of the law of reflection (be reflected the remaining length of the random radius distance selected)

[image]

Comment: Is this supposed to be some kind of random walk? If so, you should decide first what happens at the borders. If not, why not just do something like `X <- sapply(1:10,function(x) runif(5,0,2))`?

Comment: Thank you @Roland yes it falls under a random walk. I need the new centres to dall within the radius if the original centres.

Comment: You should, as @Roland said, provide the exact ruleset.  You won't need loops, due to the vectorized nature of R.   For example, borrowed from a blogger's discussion of estimating pi:  `a <- runif(n,0,1);
b <- runif(n,0,1);
# use the pythagorean theorem;
rads <- sqrt((a^2) + (b^2) )`   then it really is fastest to select all the `rads` within your limits, e.g. `rads<- rads[rads<0.2]`

Comment: If it is random walk you must define what happens if the point would move out of the square. E.g., you could say that it should adhere to physical laws of reflection. I do not think it makes sense to just say in a simulation that it doesn't happen.

Comment: yes Roland sorry for the need for babysitting. The law of reflection is how I would borders to be treated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#lets do only one point first
x <- runif(1,0,2)
y <- runif(1,0,2)


randomwalk <- function (pos) {
  x <- pos[1]
  y <- pos[2]
  radius  <- (sample(20,1,replace=TRUE))/100
  angle <- sample(360,1,replace=TRUE)
  newx <- x + radius*(cos(angle))
  newy <- y + radius*(sin(angle))

  if (newy > 2) { #check the geometric calculations
    r2 <- (2-y)/sin(angle)

    hitx <- x + r2*(cos(angle))
    hity <- 2

    newx <- hitx + (radius-r2)*sin(angle)
    newy <- hity - (radius-r2)*cos(angle)
  } 

  #implement other borders yourself
  #and include a check, which border is hit first
  #and include the possibility for multiple hits 
  #(e.g., left border and then top border)

  cbind(newx,newy)
}

resx <- vector(50,mode="numeric")
resy <- vector(50,mode="numeric")

res <- cbind(resx,resy)

res[1,] <- cbind(x,y)


for (i in 2:50) {
  res[i,] <- randomwalk(res[i-1,])
}
```

I suspect this still contains some geometric errors, but don't have time to check.

Comment: thank you Roland my geomtry is not great just trying to make sure I know what `r2` `hitx` and `newx` calculations are doing

Answer (score 1):

The functions `inpip` and `inout` from package splancs is quite useful; they can be used to check if points fall inside a polygon. You just need a matrix with 2 columns which represents any polygon (such as a square). This functions are made to be fast, using C and Fortran programs.

If your square is:

```
square <- cbind(c(0, 10, 10, 0), c(0, 0, 10, 10)) # In case side = 10
```

Then create all the new centers (I suggest using `runif` instead of `sample` for the `radii` and `angle`, but that's up to you). Then check if those centers fall inside the square with one line:

```
inside <- inout(newCenters, square)
newCenters <- newCenters[inside]
```

And afterwards you should do all the necessary steps to recreate the `newCenters` that where selected out, as many times as needed until they fall inside the square. Note that this needs a `while` loop (or equivalent).

Note also that in the same package (splancs) there is this function `csr` that create random points inside a polygon. So in principle you could cut a piece of every circumference that falls outside the square and then use the resulting polygons (the cut circles) as input to this function. This can become slow because you have to use a loop (or a `lapply` maybe) for all cut circles.

As a last idea, maybe you can combine the two strategies. First use your initial idea to all circumferences that fall completely inside the square (or equivalently, all the centers that are at a distance of 2 or more from the perimeter). Then use the `csr` function for all the rest of the circles.

Hope this helps!